# Converting WebVTT (.vtt) to VobSub (.idx / .sub)

Tags: automation, video-conversion, subtitle

There are a lot of questions about subtitle conversion, but I can't find anything for my particular use case.

I have a bunch of movies which I have previously converted to `.mp4` with `.vtt` subtitles; this was to optimize for browser-based playback, which these formats seemed to work the best in.

Now I am setting up Jellyfin and I see that VobSub has the best compatibility (it doesn't actually seem to support my `.vtt` files). I would like to convert my `.vtt` files to `.sub`/`.idx` , but I don't have access to the original `.mkv` files.

Does anyone know of a way to do this programmatically? I have a few hundred movies.

Comment: Gnome Subtitles says it supports 22 formats.